# Allow carriage return on std::getline() loop

Tags: c++, getline, istream

Is there any way to allow the user to not enter anything on this `std::getline()` loop?

```
string i;

while (true) {
    getline(cin, i);
    if (!i.empty()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The loop is there to assign multiple lines of input to a string that includes `\n`'s like this:

```
\n
Hello World!
```

Is there a way to allow the user to press enter to leave leave string i empty and leave the loop? I know this is difficult to do using `std::getline()` but I want to know if it is possible

Comment: The user can always use CTRL-D or CTRL-Z (depends on OS) to set `std::cin` into `eof()` state. Using the simply the ENTER key there's no way.

Comment: CTRL-D(on linux) is the behavior that I am looking for, is there a way to do the same thing with ENTER/RETURN?

Comment: _"is there a way to do the same thing with ENTER/RETURN?"_ No.

Comment: Based on your previous question it looks like you're thinking in the wrong direction. When I said _accumulate_ your inputs, I meant you should add them up in  a separate string. If that one isn't empty, you may leave the input loop after the user gave another empty input again.

Comment: Okay I see, that's what I'll try to get working first then work around that, thank you